# My sysdate is not the same as the date showing in my desktop

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I 've executed the following to know my sysdate and I discovered that the result is different from the date showing in my taskbar.

```
 select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS') from dual;
```

How so ? and how to fix this

Comment: Oracle installed in your PC or you connect to remote DB ?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar installed on my pc

Comment: wow, this is very rare because oracle DB take date from OS. From oracle you can only change format.

Comment: What exactly is the query result, and at that time what is your system clock showing?

Comment: query result : 09-OCT-14 03:35:02
taskbar date : 09-OCT-14 03:33:00

Answer (score 0):

Please execute the below and post what you get:

```
select 
  to_char(sysdate,'mm/dd/rr hh24:mi:ss'),
  to_char(current_date,'mm/dd/rr hh24:mi:ss'),
  systimestamp,
  sessiontimezone 
from dual;
```

Per your comment, I see there is a difference in timezone configuration. So you would need to fix your DB's timezone to match with your OS' timezone.

Comment: so respectivelly I get : 10/09/14 16:40:50   10/09/14 15:40:50  09-OCT-14 04.40.50.771000000 PM +02:00 +01:00

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz: True, I posted it as an answer instead of a comment as the SQL code in comment might get a little messy. Thanks for your suggestion, will keep this in mind in future post.

Answer (score 0):

The function sysdate is the date/time setting of the operating system where you run a certain db instance. But this is the date time (and timezone) when you start the instance and what was set in the shell or command prompt of the user (or a script) started the instance.

For example: if the timezone of a db server is set to CET and you logon this server and you open anyhow a shell with timezone configuration GMT and you (re-)start the instance in this shell then the timezone for sysdate will be GMT.

When possible re-start the instance from a shell/command prompt with that timezone configuration you like to have for your sysdate function.

BTW: systimestamp is the same as sysdate both including milliseconds but systimestamp includes also the timezone information for both sysdate and systimestamp. In addtion the function dbtimezone does not return the timezone which is used for sysdate. Only systimestamp can return the timezone of sysdate. dbtimezone is used for columns of datatype "timestamp with local timezone" nothing else.